# How to set up different inventory options for each website?

Tags: inventory

I have one Magento installation that has two websites: retail and wholesale. I have one catalog and I sell the same products in both websites.

In retail shop it's ok to sell one product at time, but at the wholesale shop it should only be possible to order at least 5 of the same product at once.

The Magento's inventory options are global. Is there a way to make them website specific?

Answer (score 2):

You can set it at customer group level, in the backend.

-> System -> Configuration 
   - Catalog | Inventory

The tab, Product Stock Options

You can see the option,  Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart.

( Text from Magento 1.7 )

The other solution is set it in a config xml, you can make a small module just for the config xml or create a new module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
 <stores>
   <storename>
    <!-- cataloginventory/item_options/min_sale_qty -->
    <cataloginventory>
            <item_options>
                    <min_sale_qty>5</min_sale_qty>
             </item_options>
     </cataloginventory>
    </storename>
</stores>
 </config>
```

To test it , you can add the stores parts also to the app/etc/local.xml

Comment: So it would seem. Thanks for that. Maybe that will do. It would however be better if I could set it up per website.

Comment: It would also be better if I could set it per product. Magento's customer group specific  setting affects all products I think.

Comment: If you really need it :) you can overwrite the file, Mage/CatalogInventory/Helper/Minsaleqty.php the function     public function getConfigValue($customerGroupId, $store = null) ask for the qty with a $store, so you can make it by yourself.